# Using Jquery, how do you change the css of the object you are clicking?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a very dynamic page which will have a lot of what we will call buttons for simplicity sake (actually are divs).

These buttons have a span tag inside which has `display:none;`. This all of these "buttons" have the Span inside with the css class which has them hidden. I can not create an #ID for each one, they are going to be dynamic

How can I, using Jquery, animate using `.show()` just the item being clicked. I can not input an ID, because it will be created dynamically with php.

Answer (score 5):

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    $(this).find('span').show();
})
```

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pD3qh/)**

Comment: This is pretty much the closest answer I guess, but as he said he didn't assign any ids. So replacing `'#button'` with `'.buttonClass'` seems to fit better in my opinion :) Upvote nonetheless.

Comment: That work BEAUTIFULLY. short, simple, and efficient. I do not suppose you can help with another small detail?

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('span').hide();
  $('.span3').click(function() {
        $(this).find('span').toggle(2000);
    });
});
  </script>

span3 will sharply jump up in height to slowly animate in "span" however it will animate out just fine smoothly. Any ideas on animating the height of span3 to the correct height before showing span? the key is knowing what height to go to.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("div").click(function(){
    $(this).children("span").show();
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uDSdX/3/)**

More information **[here](http://api.jquery.com/children/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".className or #idName").css("thecssselector", "thevalue");
```

[See Here](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Answer (score 0):

use this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("tag name or id on which you will click").click(function(){
        $("tagname on which you want to apply the css").css("property_name","property_value");
   });
});
```

Comment: Yes, but I need to do this dynamically. The object will not exist until it is created in php.

Comment: @Ampix0 that's why I am suggest you for using the .ready so that this will excute after load the page.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/damian0o/jrFBS/) have some fiddle.

```
$('div').click(function(){
    $(this).find('span').fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(".button").click(function(){
  $("div span").hide();
  $(this).find("span").show();     
});
```